# use server NIC on an pc instead of pc NIC?

Tags: nic

I want to know if I can use a "server NIC" which is PCIe (like HP server NICs) and install that on my desktop pc PCIe slot and have more features and also more ethernet ports to work with? is that possible and work???

if anyone has that experience and could help?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious hardware requirements aside:

This depends on whether there is a driver for your PCs operating system.

If not compatible you could try to force install a driver by editing its .inf file.
I once successfully used this [guide](https://blog.workinghardinit.work/2017/06/19/installing-intel-i211-i217v-i218v-i219v-drivers-windows-server-2016-eufi-boot/), although this is the other way around (client hardware for server OS).

Comment: thanks for answering ... did a lot search on google but no one did this kind of config before "server Nic on pc" but really liked your solution !!!